# React Native / Expo - building iOS app with native code

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, expo-go

In a react native expo project I am using a library that uses native code. Therefore, I cannot use expo go but instead I must use a react native cli.
If I want to change package.json or app.json I need to rebuild the app, meaning I cannot add any new libraries without the rebuild. To build for iOS I need a macbook and an authorised account and each build apparently costs. Out plan only supports 15 builds a month for each platform. Also I cannot build the app myself and always need to ask the administrator to do so for me, which is very troublesome.
Is there a workaround? Are we doing something wrong? I need to be able to run the app locally in order to work on it.